# WCF Soap Response as XML

Tags: .net, wcf

I am able to log the Soap Request using below code.

```
log.Debug( OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString());
```

The Log looks like

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hel="http://comapry.aasda.com/" xmlns:hpis="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HPIService">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <Stage>Retry</Stage>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <hel:SubmitToCompany>
         <hel:RequestData>
            <hpis:ReferenceId>1773817</hpis:ReferenceId>
            <hpis:LossDate>2014-06-02T07:20:50.202Z</hpis:LossDate>
            <hpis:Status>Error</hpis:Status>
            <hpis:State>CO</hpis:State>
            <hpis:UserId>rtrtr</hpis:UserId>
            <hpis:TransactionId>486784353</hpis:TransactionId>
         </hel:RequestData>
      </hel:SubmitToCompany>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to log the Soap Response without the use of trace listeners.

Comment: Why without trace listeners? That would allow you to just use WCF message logging. And what problem are you having? Where do you want to log to, and what's keeping you from logging there?

Comment: To keep it as simple as possible. More over I would need this response message logged only when the DEBUG logging enabled in the log4net.

Comment: Ok, so what problem are you having?

Comment: Need the simple way of capturing Soap Response. Request Soap Xml :- OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()

Comment: What's wrong with using `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()`?

Comment: That gives me the "Soap Request Xml", I am looking for "Soap Response Xml"

Comment: See [Message Inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx). Also, take a look at the other examples of WCF extensibility in the same area. If nothing else, you should have an idea of what kinds of extensibility are possible. See [Extending WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733848.aspx) for details.